# What is the difference between a higher-order function and a class?

Tags: python, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I was going through the basics of **functional programming**, and eventually came accross the concept of *higher-order functions*. I saw an example in this [video by Corey Schafer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kr0mpwqttM0) (starts at 11:00), which shows a Python function that can wrap messages in arbitrary HTML tags:

```py
def html_tag(tag):
    def wrap_text(msg):
        print('<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(tag, msg))

    return wrap_text

print_h1 = html_tag('h1')
print_h1('Test Headline!')
print_h1('Another Headline!')

print_p = html_tag('p')
print_p('Test Paragraph!')
```

Output:

```
<h1>Test Headline!</h1>
<h1>Another Headline!</h1>
<p>Test Paragraph!</p>
```

I get that it gives you the flexibility of re-using the same function for different purposes (different tags, in this example). But you could achieve the same result using Python **classes**, too:

```py
class HTML_tag:
    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag
    
    def wrap_text(self, msg):
        print('<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(self.tag, msg))

print_h1 = HTML_tag('h1')
print_h1.wrap_text('Test Headline!')
print_h1.wrap_text('Another Headline!')

print_p = HTML_tag('p')
print_p.wrap_text('Test Paragraph!')
```

Output:

```
<h1>Test Headline!</h1>
<h1>Another Headline!</h1>
<p>Test Paragraph!</p>
```

The higher-order function approach definitely looks cleaner, but apart from the aesthetics, are there any other reasons I might want to prefer a higher-order function over a class? E.g., regarding aspects like

- Performance
- Memory
- ...

Comment: Functions are easier to compose together to chain effects. If you have an `HTML_tag` class, you can achieve something similar via using the adapter pattern but then that's adapters that aren't really as generic, as they would work with an `HTML_tag` not necessarily with `XML_tag` or `JSON_value`.

Comment: You can use higher order functions to do so many things. You can time how much a function takes to execute or add attribute to your objects on the fly etc. They don't change actual behaviour of your function but *decorate* it with some functionality.

Comment: @Asocia a decorator is not synonymous with higher-order function

Comment: Classes are a poor man's closures. Closures are a poor man's classes

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Really? I mean I know they do not mean the same thing but can't we just say that they are doing the same thing? At least for python?

Comment: @Asocia well, decorators are any callable, that return a callable, that as you state, "decorate" some aspect of the functionality. Decorators are often implemented as higher order functions, but not always, and not all higher order functions are decorators. A higher order function is simply any function that takes a function as an argument or returns a function

Comment: Anyway, yes, functional programming is a paradigm that makes use of higher order functions. This is often in contrast with imperative, object-oriented paradigms that use classes. Note, functional programming doesn't necessarily exclude OOP, see the Scala programming language. But yes, these are distinct approaches to solving the same fundamental problems

Comment: If a functions returns another function this is usually called currying. A HOF takes a function as its argument. You can call a function and a method likewise but they are still totally different beasts. Hence it doesn't give you much if you compare classes with pure functions.

Comment: Higher-order functions and classes are **unrelated**, so this is effectively two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Higher order functions take and/or return functions. Let's look at both cases.

### Taking a function as a parameter

Here, a HOF is definitely the way to go. The class version amounts to a HOF with extra steps. For the class version, you need to have pre-negotiated the key the function is callable on. It's really a useless wrapper around the meat of what you're trying to accomplish.

#### HOF

```py
def my_map(fn, arr):
  result = []
  for a in arr:
    result.append(fn(a))
  return result

my_map(lambda a: a + 1, [1, 2, 3]) # [2, 3, 4]
```

#### Class version

```py
def my_map(inst, arr):
  result = []
  for a in arr:
    result.append(inst.fn(a))
  return result

class my_mapper:
  def fn(self, a):
    return a + 1

my_map(my_mapper(), [1, 2, 3]) # [2, 3, 4]
```

### Returning a function

In both versions here, what we're doing is creating an encapsulation of some value `a`, and a function that works over it.

I think that a class is generally useful if you want more than one function to be defined over some data, when the encapsulated data can change (you're encoding a state machine), or when you expect operations to be specific to your class (ie. users of your class need to know the operations defined over the class).

I would use a function that returns a function, when what I'm doing amounts to partial application, (I have a function that takes multiple parameters, and I want to preapply some, like 'add'). I would also use `functools.partial` to do this.

```py
def adder(a):
  return lambda b: a + b
```

```py
class adder_class:
  def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

  def add(self, b):
    return a + b
```

Ultimately, whether it's best to use a HOF or a class will become clear from context.